# I need to make icon to display celendar in dtoption in angular table I'm using bsdatepicker

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my code:

```
this.staffAttendanceDtOptions = Object.assign({}, this.sharedService.dtOptions);
this.staffAttendanceDtOptions.buttons = [
      {
        text: `
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt py-0 text-primary"></i>`,
        key: '1',
        title: "Add range date",
        className: 'btn  btn-outline-primary justify-content-end mr-0 ml-2 d-print-none',
        action: () => {
         this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
          // this.printPage();
     }
];
```

Comment: Can you more explain your issue ?

Comment: there's input when we click it the celender interface showing i need when i click to the icon